# Do scopes get cleaned up if they are useless?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

Pseudo example code illustrating a use case(may or may not compile)

```
+function($){
    var enableapp = 'enable-application';
    var x = function(something) {
      this.thing = something;
      this.dosomething();
    }
    x.prototype.dosomething = function() {
       console.log(this.thing);
    }
    $('[data-fancy]').each(function(index,elem) {
       var fancy = $(elem);
       if(fancy.is('[data-'+enableapp+']') && fancy.data(enableapp) == 'yes') {
          fancy.data('app', new x(fancy));
       }
       else {
           fancy.removeData('app');
       }

}(jQuery)
```

In this example I'm starting up a scoped function to register my 'applicaton' X to elements  marked with data-fancy, which have set enable-application to 'yes'

because I need to use this access key multiple times, and might be subject to frequent changes, I decided to store it in a variable in the outermost scope, where I can use it for the several checks and balances.

**My question is:**

If I don't use the `enableapp` variable in the X application, with the outermost scope get garbage collected when the intial course has been run? or will it stay in memory until the last Application object is cleared and will no more be initialised.

Comment: When you create a new closure, it will capture the outter closures if you are referencing a variable with in them. So will not lose the reference until the inner most closure is released

Comment: Here is a really good article on it https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: yes, but if it isn't referenced at all within the application, and all that lives on after the initial initialisation is the application, willl the closure get collected or will it stay alive. I'm just curious to the garbage collection mechanics.

Comment: just paste this onto the end of google ?q=javascript+garbage+collection

Comment: I've read a lot about javascript garbage collection before posting this... I'm just curious what wins,  having an object with a scope that keeps scope alive,  or a scope that gets garbage collected because its no longer referenced by active code calls. Got a google query for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `enableapp` is not referenced anywhere in the X application constructor or prototype methods and only used at definition time in the `forEach` function-- it should be garbage collected at some point.